# Grouping controls on different child pages in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

what i have done is login and the username appears in my masterpage in a label. what i need to do is if the logged in user has admin permission make visible controls on several child pages (including a gridview deletecontrol that is there on one child page). have be struggling to figure it out. just want to learn.

Is there a way to class all the controls under a class call admin and call from masterpage on checking user permission?

Loginpage code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.Adapters;

public partial class login1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = WCGSQL.showdata("select * from Login where Username='" + UserName.Text + "' and Password='" + Password.Text + "'");
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
        {

            Session["Username"] = UserName.Text;
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");

        }
        else
        {
            FailureText.Visible = true;
            FailureText.Text = "Invalid Login";
        }
    }
}
```

App/code code behind

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class WCGSQL
{
    static SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|WCG.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    static public Boolean savedata(string qurt)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qurt, con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }


    }

    static public DataSet showdata(string qurt)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(qurt, con);
            adp.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
        catch
        {
            return ds;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [LoginView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx) control. See [ASP.NET Login Controls Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx) to learn about the entire suite.

---

Example from MSDN:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
    <title>ASP.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <p>
                <asp:LoginStatus id="LoginStatus1" runat="server"></asp:LoginStatus></p>
            <p>
                <asp:LoginView id="LoginView1" runat="server">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        Please log in for personalized information.
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        Thanks for logging in 
                        <asp:LoginName id="LoginName1" runat="Server"></asp:LoginName>.
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                    <RoleGroups>
                        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Admin">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:LoginName id="LoginName2" runat="Server"></asp:LoginName>, you
                                are logged in as an administrator.
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:RoleGroup>
                    </RoleGroups>
                </asp:LoginView></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("member"))
{
  //enable/disable here
}
```

Comment: wow that sounds simple but small question here is tat part of the in built login control cause i havent used inbuilt login i use the following
`code`
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = WCGSQL.showdata("select * from Login where Username='" + UserName.Text + "' and Password='" + Password.Text + "'");
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
        {
         
            Session["Username"] = UserName.Text;
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
            
        }
        else
        {}
`code`

Comment: Mark, when the user is authenticated, do you create a ticket? please edit your question and add more code to it so we could understand what exactly is happening.

Comment: Also its a pretty non-standard way to include ad-hoc sql in your method. You could use stored procedures.

Comment: Try this sample project. It will give you a good ideahttp://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37660/Fully-configured-ASP-NET-Membership-Website-Templa

Comment: ok i edited question to add more code will also  the the given link by Tammy thx everyone for all your help it is greatly appreciated

Comment: Mark,  Please mark the answer correct if it truly helped you. I would also recommend visiting this site. They have starter project of different kinds. That would help in learning. http://www.asp.net/downloads

Answer (score -1):

Hey i'd done one application like this. What you need to do is make separate web-pages (i.e. after login pages) for both admin and other users. Then you can easily authenticate admin through his credentials and redirected to the respective page. There you can placed some controls according to the need.

And if your concern is to create an application like control-access board where admin can give permissions to modules to what to show on child pages of other users then let me know through your reply.

Comment: @Durgesh Khandal well i could do that but the fact is that both user and admin are looking at the same pages just with a few control differences and don't want to make the document bigger by duplicating the forms just for a few added commands... just to give u an example on  one page there is a GridVeiw1 and for it user has selection while admin has deletion and addition access its just a matter of making those two visible or invisible accordingly but if that is the only viable solution then i guess i will have to go with that